# How to attach the original words to LDA result set in pyspark data frame

Tags: pyspark

I have the result of a LDA in a pyspark dataframe like this:

```python
topicIndices.filter("topic > 3").show(10, truncate=True)
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|topic|         termIndices|         termWeights|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|    4| [27, 56, 29, 46, 6]|[0.01826416604834...|
|    5| [63, 4, 36, 31, 21]|[0.01900143131755...|
|    6|[40, 60, 16, 36, 50]|[0.01915052744093...|
|    7|   [5, 59, 4, 8, 29]|[0.05513279495368...|
|    8| [52, 17, 10, 46, 2]|[0.01903217569516...|
|    9|     [0, 1, 3, 7, 6]|[0.13563252276342...|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I am trying to substitute the words to the term indices in order to inspect the topics. What I am trying to do is:

```python
topics = topicIndices \
    .rdd \
    .map(lambda x: vocabList[y] for y in x[1].zip(x[2]))
```

but I get the error:

```python
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Actually, it's the Python version of this Scala code:

```python
val topics = topicIndices.map { case (terms, termWeights) =>
                terms.map(vocabList(_)).zip(termWeights)
             }
```

from [this dataBricks post](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/3741049972324885/3783546674231782/4413065072037724/latest.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lambda` expression should be into parentheses, i.e.:

```python
topics = topicIndices \
    .rdd \
    .map(lambda x: ( vocabList[y] for y in x[1].zip(x[2]) ) )
```

UPDATE (after comment): you are obviously trying to use the [PySpark `zip`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.zip), which however takes as arguments RDDs, and not lists. I *guess* (since you have not provided an example of your desired result, let alone the `vocabList` function itself) that you need the [standard Python zip function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), which has a different usage:

```python
topics = topicIndices \
    .rdd \
    .map(lambda x: ( vocabList[y] for y in zip(x[1],x[2]) ) )
```

Comment: mmm like this I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'zip'

Comment: @user299791 the error reported in your OP is due to a mistake in standard Python usage from your part, hence my answer; arguably, you are now a step closer to your real issue; [`zip`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.zip) applies to RDDs, and not to lists like your `x[1]` & `x[2]`. Kindly accept this answer, and open a new question, including an example of your **desired result**.

Comment: you have seen the edit to the question where I report the Scala code I am trying to port, haven't you?

Comment: @user299791 to put it slightly differently: before, you could not even access `x` in your code; now you can, and you see the specific issue with it...